# how to send direct messages from website to the twitter using php

Tags: php, twitter

I have developed the website and in that website i have a section called contact. In that contact section, I have provided the 2 text boxes to enter name and email and 1 text area to type the message and 1 submit button. If someone enter the name, email and message and click on submit button that message should directly go to the my twitter account. I have already created the application and got the consumerKey, consumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret.

Comment: Do you already have any code you can show us?

Comment: _“that message should directly go to the my twitter account”_ - what, in the name of _your_ account? So if I typed in “Akash likes to strangle little kittens” on your web site, you would want to immediately publish that as if you yourself had tweeted it …? Sounds rather imprudent, unsafe, and potentially it could even have legal implications ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Twitter's API to interract with Twitter website, you can find how to post a message directly on their developper docs 
You might take a look at:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/api-features

You want to send a message as YOUR account ? 
Or just post a Tweet from your website ?

And use twitter's API